Ito Calculus Solution for Path Average of Geometric Brownian Motion
I am struggling with the following question and cannot find a solution online.

Let ${X_t = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t e^{W_u} du}$, where ${W_u}$ is a standard Brownian > motion. What is the Variance of ${X_t}$?

It is clear to me that this would be the variance of a path of a geometric Brownian motion with ${\sigma = 1}$ and ${\mu = \frac{1}{2}}$. Because of this, I am expecting there to be some sort of Ito Calculus solution that doesn't involve converting things to series and taking limits, but I may be on the wrong track with that.
So far, I have done the following using Ito Calculus:
${F_t = e^{W_t}}$
${\rightarrow dF_t = e^{W_t}dt + e^{W_t}dW_t}$
${\rightarrow e^{W_t} - e^{W_0} = \int_0^t e^{W_u} du} + \int_0^t e^{W_u}dW_u$
${\rightarrow Var(\int_0^t e^{W_u} du) = Var(e^{W_t}) + Var(\int_0^t e^{W_u}dW_u) + 2 Cov(e^{W_t}, \int_0^t e^{W_u}dW_u)}$
The first component is obvious, using MGF of normal distribution. The second component is obvious using Ito's Isommetry. But I am struggling to determine ${Cov(e^{W_t}, \int_0^t e^{W_u}dW_u)}$.
Any hints in this regard or confirmation whether I'm on the right track with solving this one are much appreciated.

You application of the Ito formula to $F_t$ missed the $\frac{1}{2}$ term for $\frac{1}{2} e^W_t dt$.
But, I would chose an alternative way to do it.
Focusing on $\int_0^T e^{W_t} dt$ you need
$E \left [ \int_0^T e^{W_t} dt \right ] = \int_0^T E[e^{W_t}] dt = \int_0^T e^{\frac{1}{2}t} dt $
for the mean: remember $E$ and the integral commute.
The 2nd moment requires a minor ingenuity
$E \left [ \left ( \int_0^T e^{W_t} dt \right ) ^2 \right ] = E \left [ \left ( \int_0^T e^{W_t} dt \right ) \left ( \int_0^T e^{W_s} ds \right ) \right ] $
so you can write it as a double integral
$\int_0^T \int_0^T E \left [ e^{W_t} e^{W_s} \right ] ds \, dt$
which is
$\int_0^T \int_0^T E \left [ e^{W_t + W_s} \right ] ds \, dt$
Now $W_t + W_s$ is a normal with 0 mean and variance = $t + s + 2 \min(s, t)$ so
$\int_0^T \int_0^T e^{\frac{1}{2} (t + s + 2 \min(s, t))} ds \, dt$
which can be solved splitting the square in 2 regions where $s < t$ and $s > t$.

Thank you. The step where you convert the expectation of the product of two integrals into a double integral of the expectation of the product, how does that work. It is a property of expectation? I’m lost in that step but understand all the others.

Wait, I see now. Because you changed the integrator to ds in one of them and the expectation moves inside of both integrals then we just have basic theorem about the product of two integrals of independent variables is the double integral.

It is a very common trick when dealing with E of square of a dt integral. It allows to move the E inside.
